# How to change style and color of Table of Content?

Tags: table-of-contents, color, minitoc

I want to change style and color of my Table of Contents to match this:

[image]

Note that I use the `minitoc` package for creating my Table of Contents on a per-chapter basis.

Comment: Instead of describing your setup, It would really be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know `minitoc` well, but here's a way to obtain the desired formatting for the partial ToCs using the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package; once all the settings have been defined in the preamble, all the job is done using a single `\PartialToC` command:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\definecolor{secnum}{RGB}{13,151,225}
\definecolor{ptcbackground}{RGB}{212,237,252}
\definecolor{ptctitle}{RGB}{0,177,235}

\titlecontents{lsection}
  [5.8em]{\sffamily}
  {\color{secnum}\contentslabel{2.3em}\normalcolor}{}
  {\titlerule*[1000pc]{.}\contentspage\\\hspace*{-5.8em}\vspace*{5pt}%
    \color{white}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-15.5pt\relax}{1pt}}

\newcommand\PartialToC{%
\startcontents[chapters]%
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=ptcbackground,hidealllines=true]
\printcontents[chapters]{l}{1}{\colorbox{ptctitle}{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
    \strut\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\makebox[5em]{%
      Chapter~\thechapter\hfill}Contents}}\vskip5pt}
\end{mdframed}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter One}
\PartialToC
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\section{Section One Three}
\section{Section One Four}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\PartialToC
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}
\section{Section Three Three}

\end{document}
```

Some images of the partial ToCs:

[image]

and

[image]

In a comment to the answer has been requested to produce a similar formatting for the general table of contents; in this case, some additional works has to be done:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\definecolor{secnum}{RGB}{13,151,225}
\definecolor{ptcbackground}{RGB}{212,237,252}
\definecolor{ptctitle}{RGB}{0,177,235}

\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=ptcbackground,hidealllines=true]}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\end{mdframed}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\color{ptctitle}\contentsname}{}{}

\titlecontents{section}
  [4em]{\sffamily}
  {\color{secnum}\contentslabel{2.3em}\normalcolor}{}
  {\titlerule*[1000pc]{.}\contentspage\\\hspace*{-3em}\vspace*{2pt}%
    \color{white}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-20pt\relax}{1pt}}

\titlecontents{lsection}
  [5.8em]{\sffamily}
  {\color{secnum}\contentslabel{2.3em}\normalcolor}{}
  {\titlerule*[1000pc]{.}\contentspage\\\hspace*{-5.8em}\vspace*{2pt}%
    \color{white}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-15.5pt\relax}{1pt}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      \colorbox{ptctitle}{\strut%
        \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-7pt\relax][l]{%
          \color{white}\bfseries\sffamily#1%
          \nobreak\hfill\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}}\par\smallskip
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother
\newcommand\PartialToC{%
\startcontents[chapters]%
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=ptcbackground,hidealllines=true]
\printcontents[chapters]{l}{1}{\colorbox{ptctitle}{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
    \strut\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\makebox[5em]{%
      Chapter~\thechapter\hfill}Contents}}\vskip5pt}
\end{mdframed}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\PartialToC
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\section{Section One Three}
\section{Section One Four}

\stopcontents[chapters]
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\PartialToC
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}
\section{Section Two Three}

\stopcontents[chapters]
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\PartialToC
\section{Section Three One}
\section{Section Three Two}
\section{Section Three Three}
\section{Section Three Four}
\section{Section Three Five}

\end{document}
```

An image of the general ToC:

[image]

An image of one of the partial ToCs:

[image]

Comment: Very very thanks. how about \tableofcontents ? How to change style of table of content, same this?

Comment: @mohammadazadi please see my updated answer.

Comment: Excuse me, if i have `\subsection`, white lines not in exact position. Can you solve this problem, please?

Comment: @mohammadazadi sure; please tell me how would the formatting for subsection entries should be.

Comment: Thank you @GonzaloMedina, i use `\titlecontents{subsection}` and `\titlecontents{lsubsection}` and do this.

Comment: @mohammadazadi so is it the problem solved or do you still need some help?

Comment: Need something like that, but it multiple colors! Say, first two chapters with gray background, next two with green background etc. Still trying now... will open a new question if I cannot solve! :-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Your creativity is scattered here and there when it comes to book TOC, design, etc. Do you have all these in one file. i.e., I can use for writing books.