# Styled TOC not compiling

Tags: table-of-contents, mdframed

Done Major Edit, to make the question clear.

Removing the last chapter line works. But keeping it makes latex go crazy. It prints numbers till 65536.. and errors: ** ERROR ** Page number 65536l too large!

MikTex, XeLatex, PdfLatex (endures a few more section, but then, the same error).

Drilling down, I have found that the problem is because of mdframed, specially usetwoside option. The error also seems to be a result of the following warnings:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Errors_and_Warnings#Underfull_hbox

The log is here: http://pastebin.com/Qw58ajKF

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\definecolor{secnum}{RGB}{13,151,225}
\definecolor{ptcbackground}{RGB}{212,237,252}
\definecolor{ptctitle}{RGB}{0,177,235}

\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=ptcbackground,hidealllines=true]}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\end{mdframed}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\color{ptctitle}\contentsname}{}{}
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\titlecontents{section}
  [4em]{\sffamily}
  {\color{secnum}\contentslabel{2.3em}\normalcolor}{}
  {\titlerule*[1000pc]{.}\contentspage\\\hspace*{-3em}\vspace*{2pt}%
    \color{white}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-20pt\relax}{1pt}}

\titlecontents{lsection}
  [5.8em]{\sffamily}
  {\color{secnum}\contentslabel{2.3em}\normalcolor}{}
  {\titlerule*[1000pc]{.}\contentspage\\\hspace*{-5.8em}\vspace*{2pt}%
    \color{white}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-15.5pt\relax}{1pt}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      \colorbox{ptctitle}{\strut%
        \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-7pt\relax][l]{%
          \color{white}\bfseries\sffamily#1%
          \nobreak\hfill\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}}\par\smallskip
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother
\newcommand\PartialToC{%
\startcontents[chapters]%
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=ptcbackground,hidealllines=true]
\printcontents[chapters]{l}{1}{\colorbox{ptctitle}{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
    \strut\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\makebox[5em]{%
      Chapter~\thechapter\hfill}Contents}}\vskip5pt}
\end{mdframed}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\PartialToC
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\section{Section One Three}
\section{Section One Four}

\stopcontents[chapters]
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\PartialToC
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}
\section{Section Two Three}

\stopcontents[chapters]
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\PartialToC
\section{Section Three One}
\section{Section Three Two}
\section{Section Three Three}
\section{Section Three Four}
\section{Section Three Five}
\stopcontents[chapters]

\chapter{Chapter Three}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you have 65536 pages?

Comment: No. Only 100 pages. This toc template was found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83184/how-to-change-style-and-color-of-table-of-content
It works perfectly with the MWE provided there.

Comment: But we need also an MWE which results in your error message(s)

Comment: Added the MWE. Please see!

Comment: I ran your MWE through xelatex three times and didn't get any error messages.

Comment: Can it be platform specific? I am using MikTex.

Comment: It's possible, but seems unlikely. (I'm using XeLaTeX from TeX Live 2013, for what it's worth.)  Try deleting your .aux and .toc files and then build your MWE again. Do you get the same error? Can you paste the exact error message for us?

Comment: Yes. No matter what I do, the error repeats. Edited error msg.

Comment: Commenting out the two lines: `\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=ptcbackground,hidealllines=true]}{}{}` and `\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\end{mdframed}}{}{}` removes the error/infinite loop. So I would start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\tableofcontents` executes `\cleardoublepage` at the beginning. This leads to an endless loop. Just change the line:

```
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=ptcbackground,hidealllines=true]}{}{}
```

to

```
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=ptcbackground,hidealllines=true]\let\cleardoublepage\relax}{}{}
```

and everything works well.

Comment: These values don't work nicely for mdframed (for fullwidth), in this solution: [outermargin=\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax,innermargin=0pt]. Can you help?

Comment: @Sudhanshu: Is this related to your other question?

Comment: Yes. You marked it as duplicate so I wasn't sure where to ask..

Comment: @Sudhanshu: First I didn't notice a difference. I will have a look.