# Tufte book fullwidth across pages

Tags: tufte, fullwidth

[How to switch between two margin sizes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/how-to-switch-between-two-margin-sizes) tells a few things about this issue. But how to solve it?
MikTex, XeLatex.

```
\documentclass[nols,a4paper,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{fullwidth}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{fullwidth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: fullwidth isn't well implemented. You can achieve the same with `mdframed` which has a better splitting algorithm

Comment: \begin{mdframed}[outermargin=\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax,innermargin=0pt]
    \lipsum[2-10]
\end{mdframed}

This option works, but not with table of contents :(

Comment: In your example is no table of contents.

Comment: Yes. I asked a separate question for that. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121790/how-to-generate-a-full-width-table-of-contents-tufte-book

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121738/styled-toc-not-compiling

Comment: As it stands, I don't see how this question is really different from the linked one.