# How to generate a full width table of contents (tufte-book)?

Tags: table-of-contents, tufte, fullwidth

fullwidth environment causes trouble across pages. mdframed option too does not work well.

The mdframed answer was suggested by the author for normal text here , [How to switch between two margin sizes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/how-to-switch-between-two-margin-sizes)

```
\documentclass[nols,a4paper,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}

\hypersetup{colorlinks} % Comment this line if you don't wish to have colored links

\usepackage{lipsum,mdframed,fontspec}
\definecolor{secnum}{RGB}{13,151,225}
\definecolor{ptcbackground}{RGB}{212,237,252}
\definecolor{ptctitle}{RGB}{0,177,235}

% TOC
  \usepackage{titletoc}
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
  \pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=ptcbackground,outermargin=\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax,innermargin=0pt,hidealllines=true]\let\cleardoublepage\relax}{}{}
  \apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\end{mdframed}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Questions of Design}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Drawing}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Technique}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Design}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Drawing}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Technique}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Design}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Drawing}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Technique}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Design}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Drawing}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Technique}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That question was to fix the compilation error. This is to get the fullwidth environment.
Two separate questions so that a direct google search may easily help others.

Comment: What's the issue with this solution. You need three compilation runs.

Comment: I found the issue. You need to add the option `notoc` to the option list of tufte book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is related to the combination of the internal usage of the package `fullwidth` inside your defined outer environment. The example works well if you add the option `notoc` to your document class:

```
\documentclass[nols,a4paper,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter,notoc]{tufte-book}
```

[image]