# Table of contents placed at bottom and write above chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I don't know why the ToC is at the bottom in this WE below. Whenever I increase

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\fontsize{5cm}{5em}\bfseries} % format
  {}                % label
  {0pt}             % sep
  {\vfill\raggedleft}           % before-code
  {\vspace{4cm}\normalsize}
```

The fontsize separation the lower it gets `\fontsize{5cm}{5em}`. Any idea?

Besides, is there any way to write text above the chapter title? I want to create a kind of minitoc (both manual and automatic) on top of the chapter title on each chapter first page.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\usepackage[a5paper, 
            %hmargin = {3cm, .8in}, 
            left = 2.3cm,
            %right = 1cm,
            %width = 10.8cm,
            %height = 17cm
            ]
            {geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\fontsize{5cm}{5em}\bfseries} % format
  {}                % label
  {0pt}             % sep
  {\vfill\raggedleft}           % before-code
  {\vspace{4cm}\normalsize}

\addto\captionsUKenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {}%
}
\usepackage{titletoc}
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83184/how-to-change-style-and-color-of-table-of-content
\titlecontents{chapter}[4em]
    {}
    {\LARGE\bfseries}
    {}
    {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage\\}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf}
\newpage
\chapter{asdfasdf asdf asdf}
\newpage
\chapter{asdfasdf asdf}
\newpage
\chapter{asdfasdf asdf}
\newpage
\chapter{asdfasdf asdf}
\newpage
\chapter{asdfasdf asdf}
\newpage
\chapter{asdfasdf asdf}
\newpage
\chapter{asdfasdf asdf}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure, but i think this could be an answer to the question.

Typesetting of the chapter heading is temporarily disabled, hence no material is flushed.

[image: jlanzaToc]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\usepackage[a5paper, 
            %hmargin = {3cm, .8in}, 
    left = 2.3cm,
                %right = 1cm,
                %width = 10.8cm,
                %height = 17cm
]
{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
%{\fontsize{5cm}{5em}\bfseries}% JB I will not accept this for a page size of a5
{\Huge\bfseries} 
{}
{0pt}
{\vfill\raggedleft}
{\vspace{4cm}}

\usepackage{titletoc}
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83184/how-to-change-style-and-color-of-table-of-content
\titlecontents{chapter}[4em]{}{\large\bfseries}{}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage\endgraf}

\begin{document}
{%we use a group to limit the redefinition
\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{%do nothing
}
\tableofcontents}

\chapter{Wombats are cute}
\newpage
This is some text
\chapter{Capybaras are cool}
\newpage
\chapter{Maras are cuddly}
\newpage
\chapter{Penguins don't fly}
\newpage
\chapter{Ducks like to quack}
\newpage

\end{document}
```