# How to add color to my table of content?

Tags: color

I need the contents in blue color. Meaning that heading contents a black and all the material in blue color.
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide a MWE example and specify what you want to achive because it is not clear for me what you mean with "material". Maybe you find this answer useful? [How to change style and color of Table of Content?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83184/how-to-change-style-and-color-of-table-of-content)

Comment: @MonaIshtiaq -- please see if the answer below meets the requirement as adapted from -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555572/customizing-the-table-of-contents-with-two-colors-in-latex

Answer (score 5):

Simply use the `color` package and add one command. You have not provided an MWE so I've only provided an outline of one.

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage{color}
...
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\color{blue}}
...
\chapter{...}
% etc
```

Thanks to the comments I corrected the code above. I have also added an example output from a real document.

**EDIT 2**

Following on Werner's comment about getting different results using the `memoir` and `book` classes below are two MWEs, one for the `memoir` class and the other for the `book` class, both giving the same result for the ToC.

This is my original for the `memoir` class.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents*
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\color{blue}}
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\end{document}
```

This is for the `book` (and `report`) class:

```
\documentclass{book} \usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\color{blue}}
\clearpage
\listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoftables \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\end{document}
```

There are many LaTeX classes and if you use something other than `memoir`, `book` or `report` I have no idea what your result might be; I have no intention of checking all the possibilities.

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I think you've got one brace too much (after `\protect`).

Comment: @campa Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @Werner I have changed the code --- I must try and remember not to type code directly into an answer.

Comment: This output is [specific to `memoir`](https://pastebin.com/raw/byGYzRFM). Changing it to `book` or `report` provides a different output in terms of colour.

Comment: @Werner I have added MWEs for the `memoir` class and `book` (like `report`) class. Please go ahead and check out all the other classes that someone might use but don't expect me to respond; you could provide your own answers.

Comment: @PeterWilson: Adding [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) for the `book` example is crucial in providing the appropriate colouring, which wasn't necessary under [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) (as it already provides a comparable structure natively). Removing `tocloft` leaves some of the page numbers not coloured. That was what I was getting at...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft,xcolor}

\newcommand{\defineauthorcolor}[2]{%
    \colorlet{author#1}{#2}% Create an author colour
    \expandafter\def\csname authoredby#1\endcsname{% Create author colour settings
%       \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries\color{author#1}}% Chapter colour
        \renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\color{author#1}}% Section colour
        \renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\color{author#1}}}% Subsection colour
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\authoredby}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\@nameuse{authoredby#1}}}%
\makeatother

\defineauthorcolor{A}{blue}% Author A will be coloured blue
\defineauthorcolor{B}{blue}% Author B will be coloured blue

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \authoredby{A}
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \authoredby{B}
    \section{A section}
    \subsection{A subsection}
    \authoredby{A}
    \section{Another section}
    \subsection{Another subsection}
    \authoredby{B}
    \subsection{Yet another subsection}
    
    \chapter{Another chapter}
    \section{First section}
    \section{Second section}
    \section{Last section}
    
    \authoredby{A}
    \chapter{Last chapter}
    
\end{document}
```